# JWST Gravitational lensing

Tags: james-webb-telescope

In the JWST deep field image we see gravitational lensing but it is not there in stefans quintent image of much more massive galaxy cluster.

What are the criteria for seeing magnified images of objects via gravitational lensing (apart from the mass of the object which creates the gravitational field causing the lensing effect).

Comment: Welcome to the site. I don't see a question here, it's more of a statement, can you edit and elaborate on what you'd like to know?

Answer (score 1):

The object being imaged, the object providing the gravitational field and the observer must be co-linear (with the gravitational field object on the axis between the other two).

Images are usually curved with the radius of curvature centered on the axis. There may be multiple images of a given object, but they will all have the same radius from the axis.